# Static electricity(ESD)damage for a PCB,immediate or gradual?

Tags: pcb, esd, static-electricity

Accidentaly touched PCB of motherboard,so if it got damaged by esd would it boot?

Comment: The answer is a definite "maybe".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *Yes* and *No*. The failure type due to static can be **immediate** (which is easy to detect or perceive) or can be **latent**(hard to detect, but may surface up over a period of time). Hence the effect of ESD need not be immediate.

The PCB on the mother board have several components. The particular component which may have been completely damaged may not be involved in booting OR even normal operation of PC. Hence, even if PC boots and there is a permanent damage of one or two components it might go undetected for a while.

Since there is no practical way of identifying the latent damage of the device, always take ESD precautions while handling boards which are not meant to be handled with out such care.

Answer (score 0):

Electrostatic damage is not always immediately obvious, and when it does manifest sometimes it only effects some operations.

Maybe one of the RAM slots, SATA interfaces, front panel controls, or indicators stops working, but the system still passes POST if those features aren't being used.

Comment: So how do I figure out whether it is damaged or not?

Comment: it it works there's no way to tell for sure.

Comment: If tiny bits of paper do not get attracted to fingertips,does that mean I do not carry static electricity?